# jQuery delete trigger conditionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventtrigger

I was wondering if Javascript or jQuery have a way to delete an event listener. Let's say I want to make a function that I want to trigger only once, for example let's say I want to have a button that shows some hidden elements on the document, I would make this function (assuming the hidden elements have a `hidden` class that hides them):

```
jQuery('#toggler').click(function() {
    console.log('Hidden elements are now shown');
    jQuery('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Simple enough, right ? Now, my **actual problem** comes in, I don't want jquery to run that function again and again each time the button is clicked, because the elements are already revealed, so is there a clean way to do it ? So, in this example after clicking the toggler multiple times I want to get only one console message.

I could do `jQuery(this).unbind('click')`, but this results into removing ALL triggers and I only want to remove the current trigger.

What I usually do when I face such scenarios is solve it like this (which is **ugly** and **doesn't actually prevent code execution**, but only handles the code's results) :

```
var toggler_clicked = false;
jQuery('#toggler').click(function() {
    if(toggler_clicked) return;

    toggler_clicked = true;
    console.log('Hidden elements are now shown');
    jQuery('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Also I don't want to use jQuery's `one`, because I will have the same problem when I'll need to delete the trigger conditionally, so if you can help please give me a dynamic answer.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to name your function like that:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    console.log('Hidden elements are now shown');
    jQuery('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
};
```

And bind it this way

```
jQuery('#toggler').click(myFunction);
```

Then you can unbind it with :

```
jQuery('#toggler').off('click',myFunction);
```

Without unbinding the other listeners

Comment: Accepting this answer instead, because it gives a cleaner and more readable approach when things get more complex (eg having to rebind the trigger after it was off).

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
var myFunc = function() {
    console.log('Hidden elements are now shown');
    jQuery('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
    jQuery(this).unbind('click', myFunc);
};
jQuery('#toggler').click(myFunc);
```

This way of calling unbind is such that only the listener for myFunc handler is removed and not all the events connected to the click on the toggler.

Comment: Aha ! So unbind has a way to handle this, nice. Will check it out, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and its opposite [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) methods to attach/detach the event handler. It is the recommended way since 1.7 instead of the [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) versions that became deprecated as of jQuery 3.0.

```
$("#toggler").on("click", function(event) {
  console.log('Hidden elements are now shown');
  $('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
  // if (/* Add your condition here */) {
    $(this).off(event);
  // }
});
```

```js
$("#toggler").on("click", function(event) {
  console.log('Hidden elements are now shown');
  $('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
  // if (/* Add your condition here */) {
    $(this).off(event);
  // }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggler">Toggle</button>
<div class="hidden">
HIDDEN
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice, I think this answers my question in the cleanest way, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var myFunction = function() {
        console.log('Hidden elements are now shown');
        jQuery('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
    };
```

Add the event listener like this:

```
 jQuery('#toggler').addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

And remove it like this:

```
jQuery('#toggler').removeEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

So all together this will do the trick:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    console.log('Hidden elements are now shown');
    jQuery('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
    jQuery('#toggler').removeEventListener("click", myFunction);
};

jQuery('#toggler').addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

[more about the HTML DOM removeEventListener() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Jquery `unbind` function takes 2 parameters `eventType` and `handler`

You can put your event listener into separate function like this:

```
var clickEventHandler = function(){
  //your logic goes here
}
```

After you add listener as reference:

```
jQuery('#toggler').click(clickEventHandler);
```

And then, later, anytime, anywhere you want you can unbind that specific handler:

`jQuery('#toggler').unbind('click', clickEventHandler);`

Answer (score 1):

What i used to do in the past is toggle the click behavior using css classes, ex i used to set a click listener on the parent and delegate to all of the children something that jquery is doing now by default i believe. Anyway based on the css class it will trigger an event for ex.

```
$('.some-parent-element').on(
   'click', 
    'the-behavior-css-class', 
    function() { // do stuff here.... }
)
```

Now if you want to remove this behavior you can just toggle the class of the element and it should do the job. ex

```
$('.some-parent-element').on(
       'click', 
        'hide-me-on-click-or-whatever', 
        function() { 
            $(this).toggleClass('hide-me-on-click-or-whatever')
            // perform the action  
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the element has the class hidden

Comment: Yes, but that's not the dynamic way, it only solves the given example. Thanks though !